# android app working on emulator but connectException on device

Tags: android

the android app made  in android studio, is 
working well in emulator. its has to connect to a tcp server program that is being run in a command prompt. all this is working in emulator
but when installed in device its showing java.net.ConnectException

here is the logcat

java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.0.100 (port 8023): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)

i even tried to ping the pc from my device through terminal emulator. its working perfectly. i mean ping

Answer (score 0):

Turn off your firewall....that worked for me!